# Kubernetes Custom Operator

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator, kubernetes-custom-resources, kubernetes-egress

I have a table in a database that gets frequently updated. The table holds host/port information for Egressing. I want to create a custom operator or a custom controller to sync this information over to Kubernetes, specifically Istio ServiceEntry’s.

Is a custom operator the way to go about this? How can I keep this table and kubernetes in sync – through constant polling?

Comment: In concept this seems right, though I might restrict the term "controller" for something specifically driven by Kubernetes resources.  Do you have any code so far; is there a specific problem you're running into?

Comment: I'm using the operator-sdk to create a custom operator. From the main.go file, I am running `go controller.Sync()`. Inside of the controllers/my_controller.go file, I have the Sync() method. I am calling the sync code from the main.go file in a goroutine, so it's always running. Is there a better way to do this?